# How to print array in order have same class name div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to print array in order have same class name div. i try this code but it was print the same value of the last array. have any other way to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var sss = '5#45@41@25@65';
    var full = sss.split('#');

    var mainid = full[0];

    var full_sub = full[1].split('@');

    var sub_count = full_sub.length;

    alert(sub_count);

    for(var i=0;i<sub_count;i++)
    {
        $(".block").attr(data-id,full_sub[i]);
        $(".block").html(full_sub[i]);
    }


});
</script>


<div class="block" data-id="" ></div>
<div class="block" data-id="" ></div>
<div class="block" data-id="" ></div>
<div class="block" data-id="" ></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(".block").each(function(index)
{
     $(this).attr("data-id",full_sub[index]);
      $(this).html(full_sub[index]);
 });
```

In your code, each time you are assigning the `html()` to whole elements with the class `.block`. Here the `html()` is assigned to each tags with the same class name.
Also you forgot to put `data-id` in `""`. Otherwise it will take it as a variable, which causes the error..

Comment: You can help the OP even more if you explain your solution / the problem.

Comment: No explanation is not worth a -1, a comment asking for an explanation is fine

Comment: @Connor  is this explanation is enough?

Comment: @JuanMendes I looked at the first 5 of the answers he's given and he never explains anything, this isn't a "one-off"

Comment: @AnoopJoshi the most important part is the invalid variable which is supposed to be a string `data-id` => `'data-id'`

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Nope, that's not the most important part, the most important part is the the OP doesn't seem to be aware the the jQuery methods apply on all the matching elements. And yes, all your answers do not provide an explanation, consider improving them by helping the OP understand what the problem was instead of just fixing it for them. Teach them to fish.

Comment: @JuanMendes That's very rich considering I just had to fix your invalid answer

Comment: @Connor You fixed a very small syntax mistake, obviously a typo copied from the OP's code. You just love to complain huh?

Comment: @JuanMendes I just thought I would point it out seeing as you're claiming that all of the other answers do not provide an explanation and you didn't even point that part out, the most **important** part

Comment: @Connor I was just concentrated on providing the solutions. I will change that in my future posts,will provide more expanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code overwrites all of the elements with the class of block in each loop iteration.  Instead, create a parent element and append elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var sss = '5#45@41@25@65';
    var full = sss.split('#');

    var mainid = full[0];

    var full_sub = full[1].split('@');

    var sub_count = full_sub.length;

    alert(sub_count);
    var parent = document.querySelector('#parent');

    for(var i=0;i<sub_count;i++)
    {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div['data-id'] = full_sub[i];
        div.textContent = full_sub[i];
        parent.appendChild(div);
    }


});
</script>

<div id="parent"></div>
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rknvy/)

Comment: That's not the problem, the problem is that the OP is always calling `$(".block").html(full_sub[i]);`, which is setting all `.block`s to the same value, so you only get the last one, once you get out of the loop

Comment: I'm aware of that, my code solves it.  Check out the JSFiddle link

Comment: But it doesn't explain what the problem is

Comment: @JuanMendes Clarified, is that better?

Comment: It is better, but you're working around the problem. The OP misunderstood the concept of calling methods on a set of elements. It's better to keep the divs there and still get the correct behavior, while teaching the OP how to fix it without changing the approach

Answer (score 1):

If you do that way it will always print the same value of the last array.

You should use JQuery **append** function to append block div into a wrap div.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>  
  $(document).ready(function(e) {

    var sss = '5#45@41@25@65';
    var full = sss.split('#');

    var mainid = full[0];

    var full_sub = full[1].split('@');

    var sub_count = full_sub.length;

    alert(sub_count);

    for(var i=0;i<sub_count;i++)
    {
        $("#wrapBlock").append('<div class="block" data-id="'+ full_sub[i] +'">'+ full_sub[i] +'</div>');       
    }


    });
</script>


<div id="wrapBlock"></div>
```

That's my solution, hopefully it's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="block" ></div>
<div class="block" ></div>
<div class="block" ></div>
<div class="block" ></div>
```

**Script**

```
var sss = '5#45@41@25@65',
    full = sss.split('#'),
    full_sub = full[1].split('@');

$('.block').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('data-id', full_sub[index]);
    $(this).html(index+1);
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/E5vB8/3/)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when you call `$(".block").html(full_sub[i]);`, you are setting it on all the divs with class `.block`; By doing the loop, you overwrite them each time and once you get out of the loop, they are set to the last value

Anoop's code works, an alternative is

```
var blocks = $(".block");
for(var i=0;i<sub_count;i++)
{
    $(blocks[i]).attr('data-id',full_sub[i]);
    $(blocks[i]).html(full_sub[i]);
}
```

The trick is that you can get at each of the items in jQuery's collection by using `obj[intIndex]` so that you're not dealing with all of them.

The each method is the jQuery way of doing it, it will iterate through each of the elements in the jQuery object, passing it the index, and `this` will point to the element being iterated

```
$(".block").each(function(index) {
     $(this).attr("data-id",full_sub[index]);
     $(this).html(full_sub[index]);
 });
```

Comment: I didnt downvote you. But i think the problem is with data-id, you forgot yo put it in ""